# CakePHP: add fields to form (dynamically)

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am trying to dynamically add fields to my CakePHP form, but it seems that each method I used had its own downsides which I couldn't fix. Here is what I tried:

1. Don't add a new input, just separate the values in a single input with a comma. It seemed pretty easy, with some problems when trying to explode the input and save each value in a new row in the database. But I abandoned the idea when I had to edit these values...gather all the values and implode them in an input, then when I saved check whether all values are still there, if not, delete the corresponding row from the table...To much work to do.
2. I tried creating new inputs on the fly, with JS. But here, I stumbled upon 2 problems: the Security component, which was throwing a blackhole attempt (and I really need this component to check the integrity of the form) and the fact that if validation fails, my inputs will disappear together with their values. I must add that a single Model may have unlimited fields, so the inputs will be something like `name=[Model][14][field], name=[Model][17][field]`, therefore I can't restrict the Security component not to validate those certain inputs (I know their IDs only when I add them with JS, anyway, way after the Security component builds its data).
3. Adding fields with PHP (therefore, reload the page after a new field is added), but I cannot seem to find out how do I add a field exactly after another present field, and also, how to maintain the input's data upon validation errors.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I don't think it's possible to use the Security component AND add fields to the form. The whole point of securing the form is to checksum it and ensure that no fields are added or removed. Can you try to do it without the Security Component and find another way to ensure your form is locked down?

Comment: OK, lets say I don't use the Security component. Then how do I validate all added fields, and retrieve their value if the form didn't validate?

Comment: That's form validation, done in the model. Very different from what the Security component does. I'd leave the Security Component to the side, unless your app absolutely must have it, and just validate the form inputs in the model. There's more info on validating for inputs here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/125/Data-Validation

Comment: The thing is that I have a main model in my form, and then all associated categories. Moreover, these categories can contain multiple values, so that the number of categories to be saved is dynamic and I don't know how to retrieve exactly which categories were populated, together with their id (`Model.0.field`, `Model.1.field`, ..., `Model.n.field`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure I can give you a full answer to your question, but hopefully I can give you a couple ideas.

I found myself in a similar situation when trying to create an admin system for polls.

Each Poll had many PollOptions and I wanted to make it possible to dynamically add as many poll options as needed on my polls/admin_edit page.

I managed this with CakePHP's built-in functionality plus a bit of Javascript.

When building the form in the admin_edit view, I first put in the Poll fields and under that I added this:

```
<div id="poll-options">
<?php 
if (isset($this->data['PollOption'])) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($this->data['PollOption'] as $opt) {
        echo $form->hidden("PollOption.$i.id");
        echo $form->input("PollOption.$i.name", array('label' => "Option " . ($i + 1)));
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

`$this->data` was set in PollsController. If the Poll already had related PollOptions, they were also included in `$this->data`. Also, if the form had already been submitted and there were validation errors, all the needed PollOption fields were built again when the page displayed because they were still in `$this->data` from the controller.

So that took care of making sure I always had the fields I needed in the view.

When the form was submitted, I attempted to save the data with a simple

```
$this->Poll->saveAll($this->data, array('atomic' => false, 'validate' => 'first'));
```

(You can check the CakePHP API or docs if you're not sure of the above syntax)

I used Javascript (jQuery) to dynamically add the PollOption fields:

```
$('#add-option-button').click(function(event){
    var optionCount = $('#poll-options > div').size() + 1;
    var inputHtml = '<div class="input text"><label for="PollOption' + optionCount + 'Name">Option ' + optionCount
        + '</label><input id="PollOption' + optionCount + 'Name" type="text" name="data[PollOption][' + optionCount + '][name]" /></div>';
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#poll-options').append(inputHtml);
});
```

You mentioned you were doing this yourself, but you shouldn't have any trouble with it if you don't try to use the Security component on the form.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction, or maybe give you some ideas.

Comment: Sounds like what I need. My logic is more complicated, but I am sure I will handle it after your detailed example. Thank you very much, it is what I've needed!

Comment: form generation is being done with jquery manually(hardcoded) and not using the cake form helper, this gets a little messy when generating large/many forms. I'm thinking - is there a way to use the Js helper along with the form helper to achieve the same?

Comment: Ankan, I'm wondering the same, I have some pretty complicated forms and have been using jQuery's .clone() method to make a copy of Cake's autogenerated form fields then editing ids etc using .replace(), it doesn't feel very robust to me though, would rather there was a feature in FormHelper or JsHelper to support multiple entries for hasMany relationships.

Comment: adding dynamically fields how is possible to use cakephp validation rules?
Because if you do it the input generate by jquery(client size) you will not have any validation rules of course you can make client side validation rules but we know that it is not so secure.

Answer (score 1):

in some case  this solution:

```
 var optionCount = $('#poll-options > div').size() + 1;
```

can override your old data in scenario when cake find existing id (optionCount) in db.
if u are adding new data iteration index should be generated by uniq generator..