# Adding input fields to a cakephp form through admin

Tags: php, cakephp

I am struggling to find out if I can do this but I have a cakephp form with many input fields and when submitted I write them to a text file I can add fields in dynamically here by clicking a button but:

My question is if I have an admin page how do I get that to dynamically add fields to the page and make them stay there forever not just for that session?

Really stuck figuring out how to do this any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make them persistent. You need to store the form and the fields it has: "Form hasMany FormField". The fields should describe a type so that the FormHelper will render the correct inputs.

When you want to display the form read that information from the db again and render the form according to your stored information.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you already have a javascript function that dynamically adds the field to your admin page. Is that correct?

I don't use CakePHP, but a general workaround I use is to use the javascript function to at the same time update a table in the database that stores the form layout.

Comment: Yep I have a jquery function which adds the fields and ye a database looks like the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Jquery Form builder plugins that you can use to achieve the goal.

1. http://www.berthou.com/us/2009/09/05/dynamic-forms-builder-with-jquery/
2. https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.formbuilder
3. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-builder-plugin/
4. http://www.elizaibeth.com/2010/11/23/dynamic-jquery-form-builders/

Here is an excellent link of [PHP FormBuilder class](http://www.designaeon.com/php-form-builder-class/) with tutorial, that you can use as a vendor library into CakePHP.

Comment: This link also might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002078/cakephp-add-fields-to-form-dynamically